# Sum Value as per case in MySql

Tags: mysql

As per below MySql Query fetch product count correctly see the red box in image. I need if **icat_id** 444 than 448 count (158) **SUM** in **category_count** (435) of **icat_id** 444.

After this **icat_id** 444 total sum of 435 + 158 = 593.

But Case not working properly. Please help

```
SELECT c.vcategory, c.icat_id, 
COUNT( DISTINCT product_cat_rel_1.iprod_id) AS category_count, 
UPPER(REGEXP_REPLACE(CONCAT(' ', c.vcategory), ' (.)[^ ]+', '\\1' ))  AS category_name,
SUM(CASE WHEN (c.icat_id = '444') THEN 1 WHEN (c.icat_id = '448') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS tt


 FROM product 
 INNER JOIN product_cat_rel_1 ON product_cat_rel_1.iprod_id = product.iprod_id 
 INNER JOIN product_price ON product_price.iprod_id = product.iprod_id 
 INNER JOIN category as c ON c.icat_id = product_cat_rel_1.icat_id 
 WHERE product.estatus='1' 
 AND product_cat_rel_1.icat_id in (444,448,450,454,471,549,592,741,765,782) 
 GROUP BY product_cat_rel_1.icat_id
```

[image]

Comment: please read up on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and produce a ]mre] in text

Comment: will icat_id 444 for both icat_id (444, 448) and sum of both value?

Comment: I need 448 value sum in 444 value and 444 value will be 593.

Comment: @AbidHussain please check the below query. Rewrite your given query by adding required logic at SELECT and GROUP BY section.

Answer (score 1):

As per requirement group by both 444 and 448 as 444 and sum up corresponding value. Apply changes in given query.

```
-- MySQL
SELECT c.vcategory, 
     CASE WHEN product_cat_rel_1.icat_id IN (444, 448)
                  THEN  444
               ELSE product_cat_rel_1.icat_id
          END icat_id, 
COUNT( DISTINCT product_cat_rel_1.iprod_id) AS category_count, 
UPPER(REGEXP_REPLACE(CONCAT(' ', c.vcategory), ' (.)[^ ]+', '\\1' ))  AS category_name,
SUM(category_count) AS tt
 FROM product 
 INNER JOIN product_cat_rel_1 ON product_cat_rel_1.iprod_id = product.iprod_id 
 INNER JOIN product_price ON product_price.iprod_id = product.iprod_id 
 INNER JOIN category as c ON c.icat_id = product_cat_rel_1.icat_id 
 WHERE product.estatus='1' 
 AND product_cat_rel_1.icat_id in (444,448,450,454,471,549,592,741,765,782) 
 GROUP BY CASE WHEN product_cat_rel_1.icat_id IN (444, 448)
                  THEN  444
               ELSE product_cat_rel_1.icat_id
          END
```